# Reskit - callback on the same thread instead of UI thread

Tags: ios, ios8, restkit

I am performing getObjectsAtPath in a background thread. However, the success/failure blocks are called on the UI thread.

Is there a way to force RestKit to call success and failure blocks on the same thread instead on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restkit does not provide this functionality, but you can archive this.

`RKObjectRequestOperation` class has two properties `successCallbackQueue` & `failureCallbackQueue`, which are allows you to set call back queue. Overwrite `RKObjectManager` class and return `RKObjectRequestOperation` then you can set callback queues.

```
- (RKObjectRequestOperation *)getObjectsAtPath:(NSString *)path
          parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
             success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
             failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSParameterAssert(path);
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:path parameters:parameters];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    [self enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
    return operation;
}
```

Then you can set callback queues as shown bellow:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:path
                     parameters:parameters
                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                        }
                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                        }];

operation.successCallbackQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
operation.failureCallbackQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
```